# Basic access authentication in Chrome url fails (http)

Tags: google-chrome, parsing, basic-authentication, url-parsing

Since few days, I noticed an issue in url parsing in chrome that worked previously.

Indeed when using basic access authentification directly in url using a iframe or an anchor html tag, the final reached link is not correct.

For instance from the domain1.tld's page:

```
<iframe src="https://bob:thepasswd@domain2.tld"></iframe>
```

or

```
<a href="https://bob:thepasswd@domain2.tld">Test</a>
```

will result in accessing the url

```
https://domain1.tld/https:/bob:thepasswd@domain2.tld
```

Please note that SSL certificates are valid and cross domain directive is set.
No message from debug console.

Chrome versions tested (under windows 10 x64):

- 52.0.2743.116 m does not work
- 53.0.2785.113 m does not work
- 55.0.2860.0 canary (64-bit) does not work

Firefox and Opera works correctly.

Am I missing something or is it a known issue? Not found more on the web.

Answer (score 0):

However, many modern browsers no longer support this in links

[INFO:](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=82250#c7)